# How to avoid Bootstrap .hidden-xs behavior to show all table columns while printing?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, printing

I want to add print feature for some of my projects written based on Bootstrap. In some pages, I have tables with many columns. I used `.hidden-xs` for some columns to avoid showing them on mobile devices. But this caused a problem for printing.
When I want to print the table in Chrome on my laptop, no `.hidden-xs` column is visible! Whereas I have not such problem on Firefox.

Do you have any idea to solve this issue? I wrote the code below but it did not work.

```
@media print {
    td,td {
        display: table-cell !important
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't follow the `print` media query.
What you can do instead is add a print specific stylesheet by using the media attribute in the link tag and specifying all print styles in there.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/print.css" media="print">`

Comment: What I mentioned in the question is the only problem I have on Chrome using print media query. Everything else are working well ...

Comment: well hidden-xs also uses !important so you will either need to make sure that your media query comes after bootstrap or that you provide more specificity. with somethings like table>tr>td.hidden-xs {display: table-cell !important}

Comment: I used my custom css file after loading Bootstrap files. Your next code did not change anything.

Comment: That code wasn't supposed to work out of the box, I don't know what your table structure looks like it was just meant to show added specificity.  Also there is no reason to have td,td the comma is used for applying styles to multiple selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set higher priority on media print, it works on chrome as well, just do something like this:

```
@media print {
    body#home .container table td,td { /* Change this with specific classes/elements on your page /*
        display: table-cell !important
    }
}
```

and then try... If you have 2 !important, one with more specific definition will override another.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem using this code:

```
@media print {
    td.hidden-xs, th.hidden-xs {
        display: table-cell !important
    }
}
```